# Printer issues using Citrix?

Tags: remote-access, printing, citrix, microsoft-dynamics-crm, crm

We have remote users using Citrix using CRM 4.0 for Outlook 2003. The CRM 4.0 Application is customized and connects to a sharepoint document library.  When the user tries to print from the document library within CRM 4.0 the pages come out black.  What could be causing this issue.

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of printer(s) and which printer driver you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Citrix UPD (Universal Print Driver?)

Answer (score 1):

Seen this with HP drivers, see if you can swap between PCL5 and PCL6 driver. Also does this document happen to landscape?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using legacy printing // universal printer driver
This is described [right here in this kb](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenapp-and-xendesktop/7-15-ltsr/policies/reference/ica-policy-settings/printing-policy-settings/client-printers-policy-settings.html) and might help your cause, because that looks like one of those kind of problems, especially looking at the fact that Outlook 2003 is .. outdated to say at least.